# No distribution matching the version for dronekit error when installing dronekit-Python

Tags: dronekit-python

Followed all instructions on 3D Robotics Getting Started page for Windows installation of Dronekit-python.

As per instructions, installed `WinPython` to use `dronekit-python`.

As per instructions I open the `WinPython Command Prompt` and ran the following command:

```
pip install dronekit
```

Get error that says "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dronekit"

and "No distribution matching the version for dronekit"

Please advise.

Using Windows 8.1

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Pypi has only dronekit for Python 2.7.
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dronekit

If you are using a WinPython3, that would explain the message.

Comment: I am using the Link that is given in the instructions on the 3D Robotics website to install WinPython.  I have confirmed it is Python 2.7.

Comment: Also...just got DroneKit to install.

There is a bug in the 3D Robotics instructions on Website.

"pip install dronekit" gives me errors and does not install the latest version.

I have to specify which version I want:

"pip install dronekit=2.0.0rc4"....which is the latest.

Also get a notice during install that says "skipping mavnative due to windows possibly missing a compiler"